# Show that $f=0$

Tags: integration, derivatives, continuity

[image]>Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$.

> Assume that for every  function $h\in C^2[a,b]$ with $h(a)=h(b)=0$ we have $\int _a^b h(x)f(x)dx=0$
>
> Show that $f=0$

Assume that $f\neq 0\implies \exists c\in [a,b] $ such that $f(c)\neq 0$.
Without loss of generality let $f(c)>0$.
Since $f$ is continuous so $\exists \delta >0$ such that $f(x)>0\forall x\in (c-\delta,c+\delta$.

But I cant proceed after that.
Can someone help.

Comment: You can find $C^2$ function that is 0 outside this interval and positive inside.

Answer (score 4):

You can say more than $f(x)>0$ on $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$, you can say there exists $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)  \geq \epsilon$ on $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$ (do you see why?).

Now find $h\in C^2[a,b]$ such that:

- $h=0$ outside of $(c-\delta/2,c+\delta/2)$
- $h \geq d $ for some constant $d$ on $(c-\delta/2,c+\delta/2)$
- $\int_a^b h(x) \ dx >0$.

Show that for such an $h$, $\int_a^b f(x)h(x) \ dx >0$.

Comment: I dont see why? can you explain?

Comment: If $f(c)>0$, then there exists some positive number $d$ such that $f(x)=d$. Choose some $0<\epsilon<d$ Then for a certain choice of $\delta$, you know $f(x)$ is within $\delta-\epsilon$ of $f(c)$ whenever $x$ is within $\delta$ of $c$.

Comment: But I dont see why is that needed to answer the question ,I find that  $f(x)>0$  solves it .Isn't it?

Comment: And one more question :why is the assumption that $h\in C^2$ is needed?

Comment: If you take for granted that the integral of a positive, continuous function on an interval of nonzero length is positive, then sure all you need is $f(x)>0$.

Comment: And why is $h\in C^2$ needed?

Comment: The assumption that $h \in C^2$ is not necessary, but it makes the result stronger. Certainly the result is true if you only require $h$ to be continuous, but that imposes more conditions: you need $\int_a^b f(x)h(x) \ dx = 0$ for *all* continuous functions $h$. The theorem in your question says actually that's not necessary. It suffices to check $\int_a^b f(x)h(x) \ dx = 0$ just for functions $h$ that are in $C^2$ (a smaller class of functions). The result could be made even stronger by saying you only need $h \in C^\infty$.

Comment: And why do we need to have $h(x)>0 \forall x\in (c-\frac{\delta }{2},c+\frac{\delta}{2})$ ? Why cant we take it on $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$

Comment: Oops, typo. I meant to say $h(x) \geq d$ for some constant $d$ for $x \in (c-\delta/2,c+\delta/2)$. The reason for restricting this interval is because $h$ is continuous, so we need to allow "space" for $h(x)$ to go down to $0$ outside of $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$.

Comment: I still don't get it.Why cant we construct a continuous function $h$ such that $h(x)>0$  forall $x\in (c-\delta,c+\delta) $ and $0$ elsewhere.I am attaching a picture in my question.Kindly check and revert where is the problem in the picture

Comment: That $h$ doesn't look $C^2$ to me. In any case, sure it is enough to take $h>0$ on $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$, but that is if you are taking for granted the fact that the integral of a positive function over an interval of nonzero length is positive, which I did not take for granted in my answer.